# jsonp return number

Tags: arrays, numbers, jsonp

Hi in my succes function im trying to return 6 numbers from my callback jsonp function and pass to a var, something like; im out of ideas thnx P

```
for (var bw=0; bw < bw_numbers.length; x++) {

$('#_pnl' + bw).innerHTML = bw_numbers[bw];
                            }



jsonCallback(
   {
         "bw_numbers": [10, 12, 15, 24, 27, 41]

     }

);
```

var url = 'http://www.blabla.com/ajax/bw_results_latest.json?callback=?';

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    async: false,
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',

                    success: function(json) {


            //do my array thing!!!!         

                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            alert(e.message);
                            }
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now, I wasnt sure if the json data was able to be used as an array, it is and here is code! Thanks P

var url = 'http://www.blabla.com/ajax/results_latest.json?callback=?';

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    processData: true,
                    async: false,
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',

                    success: function (data) {
                        processData(data);
                        }
                    });

                function processData(data){

                    for (var x=0; x < data.bw_numbers.length; x++) {
                        document.getElementById('_pnl' + x).innerHTML = data.bw_numbers[x];
                     }




                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the jsonCallBack function

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                error: function(e) {
                        alert(e.message);
                        }
             });
function jsonCallBack(data)
{ alert(data); }
```

If you return like

```
jsonCallback([10, 12, 15, 24, 27, 41])
```

you can access it as array from javascript

Comment: Thanx but that does not work! I can use the json data in the success function like so: success: function (json) {       $(".results").html( json.bw_numbers );       
}, but what I need is to be able to work with bw_numbers as an array, cheers P